# How to show that $(\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{q})^2 + \|\mathbf{p} \times \mathbf{q}\|^2 = \|\mathbf{p}\|^2\|\mathbf{q}\|^2$

Tags: calculus, vectors

How to show that $$(\mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{q})^2 + \|\mathbf{p} \times \mathbf{q}\|^2 = \|\mathbf{p}\|^2\|\mathbf{q}\|^2$$ for vectors $\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q} \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbf p,\mathbf q\in\mathbb R^\color{red}n$?  Can you use that $ ||\mathbf p\times\mathbf  q||=||\mathbf p||||\mathbf q||\sin(\theta)$ and $||\mathbf p\cdot \mathbf q||=||\mathbf p||||\mathbf q ||\cos(\theta)$?

Comment: FYI you don't need to enclose *every* [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) command in its own set of `$...$`, take a look at the edits.